# I am not able to run gitleaks docker image

Tags: docker, gitleaks

I am trying to run the gitleaks docker image, but it is not scanning the code and giving me the error. But if I am doing the same by installing gitleaks then it is scanning the entire code.

I am using webgoat as vulnerable code for scanning and below is my sample command.

```
    docker run -v /Users/<Path>/WebGoat/ zricethezav/gitleaks:latest detect -v --source .
```

As i am trying to map the official gitleaks command i.e.

```
    docker run -v ${path_to_host_folder_to_scan}:/path zricethezav/gitleaks:latest [COMMAND] --source="/path"
```

It is giving me an error i.e.

```
        ○
        │╲
        │ ○
        ○ ░
        ░    gitleaks
    
    7:07PM ERR [git] fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    7:07PM ERR git error encountered, see logs
    7:07PM WRN partial scan completed in 60.5ms
    7:07PM WRN no leaks found in partial scan
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your command needs to be more like this:

```bash
docker run -v /Users/<Path>/WebGoat:/path zricethezav/gitleaks:latest detect -v --source /path
```

The format of the `-v` argument for docker is `{host_dir}:{container_dir}` telling Docker to mount the `host_dir` directory at the location of `container_dir` inside your running container. I presume the `--path` argument tells gitleaks in which directory to scan. This should be the location you've mounted the volume inside the container. Passing `.` like you did will make it scan the current work directory of the process running inside the container I think.

You can find more details about volume mounting in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only)